# angular Ng-options error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use an ng-option based drop down. My code currently looks like this:

```
<select
     ng-options="choice.id as choice.singular in model.quanityChoices"
     ng-model="med.id"
     <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

The model data this is based off looks like this:

```
[
 {id: 1, singular: 'word'},
 {id: 2, singular: 'word2'}
]
```

Currently my goal is to have a dropdown where the user will see the options 'word' and 'words' but the value that gets applied is the ID.

Currently my code has the following error:

```
Error: [ngOptions:iexp] Expected expression in form of '_select_ (as _label_)? for (_key_,)?_value_ in _collection_' but got 'choice.id as choice.singular in model.quantityFormChoices'. Element: <select...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't structure it correctly, look at the error as it gives you the details on how to do it:

```
<select
     ng-options="choice.id as choice.singular for choice in model.quanityChoices"
     ng-model="med.id"
     <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Oh wow yes this was obvious, I had been comparing it to another ng-option I had in the code and I didn't notice that it was missing the "for choice in" part.

Comment: Sorry about that, nearly sure I clicked on it!, But as  recent history has shown my attention to detail is low =)